# How to determine if a following phrase applies to both of the subjects that are connected with "and" or "or"

Tags: sentence

The title is way too long and not that accurate I think.
The example is this:

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to a colleague or
>   somebody seeking software solutions?

When it comes to this kind of sentences, I always wonder if it means:

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to a colleague
>   seeking software solutions or somebody seeking software solutions?

or

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to a colleague or
>   somebody seeking software solutions?

Is there any way to determine if a following phrase (in this case, "seeking software solutions") applies to both of the subjects or just the one right before the phrase? Does it depend on context?

Comment: A comma would be  needed to disambiguate if it is not clear from context.  "{recommend this product to {a colleague} **, (comma)** or {somebody seeking software solutions}} vs. {recommend this product to {a colleague or somebody} {seeking software solutions}} HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is context that determines the interpretation.

Syntactically, the sentence is ambiguous. But it's not ambiguous semantically.

It makes no sense to specify:

1. a colleague seeking software solutions
2. somebody seeking software solutions

A colleague *is* somebody, so it's redundant. It would be the same type of thing as a longer sentence:

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to a colleague seeking software solutions or a priest seeking software solutions or a plumber seeking software solutions or a doctor seeking software solutions or somebody seeking software solutions?

The use of *somebody* at the end, when used in this general sense, includes *anybody* seeking software solutions; therefore, there's no need to enumerate additional list items.

If all you're really interested in is *somebody seeking software solutions* (whether a colleague or anybody else), then that's *all* you need to say:

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to somebody seeking software solutions?

So, the only reason for a colleague to be specified is if they fall into some category that is **not** *somebody seeking software solutions*.

Since that category has not been noted, the most reasonable interpretation of the sentence is:

> How likely would you be to recommend this product to either a colleague **in general** or to somebody who is seeking software solutions **specifically**?

Also note how my rephrasing of the sentence results in it no longer being ambiguous syntactically.